# XML parser written in pure javascript for embedded environments

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-parsing

I'm looking for a parser which can run in a javascript environment where there is no access to `document`, `DOMParser` or any other browser extension. The javascript application can run in browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari...) in node.js but it is destined to run mainly embedded in a V8 or in a SpiderMonkey environment. The environment is distributed without support for the usual XML parsers and I am unable to parse a string containing valid XML from javascript.

All libraries which rely on browser extensions like `DOMParser` and `ActiveXObject` fail with messages like **`ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined`**.

Access to file system is not necessary (I need to parse from string to a DOM-like structure).

Comment: Googling `javascript parse xml` shows lots of useless results (using browser capabilities) but also some useful ones

Comment: Useful answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7373003/1388017

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9056881/187606 it doesn't outright *say* it's a complete native implementation but it looks like one

Comment: xhr's responseXML is a pure parsed DOM. btw what you mean by no browser parser?

Comment: @cocco A parser that uses no browser extensions like ActiveXObject  or DOMParser. Simply put by providing a pure javascript implementation.

Comment: @Pekka웃 [marknote](https://code.google.com/p/marknote/wiki/DevelopersGuide) is indeed a pure js implementation. I'll use that. Thank you!

Comment: if new XMLHttpRequest is aviable you prolly can use just the responseXML.

Comment: @cocco I need to load the XML from memory and eventually from files too but the files are uncompressed by C++ and transferred to javascript as strings. So I need to read the strings.

Comment: i added an example marknote  uses ajax. yeah reading strings is not possible.. but if that works reading files it's for sure faster than using the makernote parser.

Comment: @cocco : parseURL() uses ajax but parse() runs its own parser. It parses strings.

Comment: i understand... wasn't 100% sure of your question and what the c++ can handle.

Comment: I don't see why this question is off topic. The requirement is very specific and there are no solutions specifically created for this context. If this question is off-topic all other questions about libraries for nodejs, spider monkey, python, php etc are off-topic. i.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14890655/171711

Comment: @Quentin I think the question Makes more sense now. It was badly worded and lacked the context in its previous form, could be reopened now I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[marknote](https://code.google.com/p/marknote/wiki/DevelopersGuide) is the right solution as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056881/187606) (thanks to Pekka 웃). The library uses XMLHttpRequest when loading from remote locations, but when parsing from a string it integrates a standalone XML parser written in javascript, which makes it suitable for use in embedded interpreters :

```
var text="<note>";
text=text+"<content>whatever blablabla</content>";
text=text+"</note>";


var parser = new marknote.Parser();
var doc = parser.parse(text);

native.log(doc.toString()); // show the formatted XML
```

Comment: There are [many](https://npms.io/search?q=fast+xml+parser) pure js solutions are available now.

Answer (score -5):

Checkout [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) - a basic XML parser.

Comment: Actually this is exactly what the OP excludes: as per JQuery source: `new DOMParser();` this is a browser extension. Jquery simply hides the parser implementation (ActiveXObject and DOMParser).