# Regex capture group between two non groups

Tags: javascript, regex

**Updated** I'm trying to match all the `['ta]` character(s) between two non capture groups like this (static xml):

Example xml

```
<Monkey xmlns="http://urlhere.com/monkeynamespace">
 <foodType>
  <vegtables>
   <carrots>i don't like carrots, or tomatoes</carrots>
  </vegtables>
 <foodType>   
</Monkey>
```

And my regex

`/(?:(<.*?>))(['ta])(?:(<\/.*?>))/gm`

Any ideas? Seems like that regex turns lazy.

Comment: If the xml is dynamic; I'll recommend using parser for it. Otherwise; does [this](https://regex101.com/r/aTH2Y0/1) help?

Comment: you aren't accounting for any of the other characters around the `'` "I don" and "t like carrots"

Comment: [You should not match XML with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/519360) unless it's generated and you have a full understanding of what that generator is capable of. What happens given `<vegetables color='orange'><carrots>i don't like carrots</carrots></vegetables>`?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Nice, but for some reason it's lazy. I was unable to modify it to also capture a `c`, like this `['c]`

Comment: @AdamKatz It's static. Only the content can change

Comment: Are you trying to match tag values? eg `i don't like carrots` from `<carrots>i don't like carrots</carrots>`? What was your intention when you coded `['ta]`?

Comment: @Bohemian Trying to match all `t`, `a`, `'` from the string `i don't like carrots, or tomatoes`. Did a small update

Comment: why are you not using xml parser?

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Not possible. Can only use ecma* JS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692837/xml-parser-written-in-pure-javascript-for-embedded-environments

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Nice! Let me try it if it works in my closed environment

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Sorry, didn't work -> 'DOMParser is not defined'

Comment: no the fiddle the so link it contains a js lib for the same i guess

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Nope, I can only use javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
['ta](?=[^<>]*<)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/zGxdJ6zGFisBfv).

It's not bulletproof, but works for your sample and will work for typical xml.

It works by matching `['ta]` only when the *next* angle bracket in the input is a *left* angle braket.