# What could be the possible reason of fs.lstat() Enoent error?

Tags: linux, node.js

i am right now debugging one system and in the log i am getting ENOENT lstat error. code is as follows.

 `fs.lstat(self.file, function(err, stats) {
        if(err) {
                  //rest of the code.
            return;
        }`

What i want to know is what is the possible reason of ENOENT error.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you read the *many* matches a search on google returns for ENOENT nodejs ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504919/node-js-error-enoent-open-file-path-when-nothing-has-been-changed

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat

Comment: Could it be that you don't have permission on that directory?

Comment: @dystroy i have read all of them.

Comment: What is returned from `self.file` ? Watch out for the spaces before and after if there are any

Comment: self.file is file name coming from HTTP API Request.

Comment: From the `man` page for `lstat`, `ENOENT` means "A component of `path` does not exist, or `path` is an empty string.". It might be worded differently in different versions of the documentation, but it basically means that the path you are trying to check does not exist, either because it's an empty string, or because walking the path failed at some point due to a missing directory or file component.

Answer (score 4):

`ENOENT` means there is no such file or directory.

Comment: That's obvious, Post a possible solution if you have any.

Comment: @Салман What do you mean by „solution”? To which problem?  I've answered the question. That's the possible reason why `fstat()` returns `ENOENT`. If the OP wanted to know something different, the question should have been different. ;-)

Comment: Possible solution: remove the `fs.lstat` call from the code. Code that doesn't exist cannot fault.

Comment: Why should i remove fs.lstat() ? This is a code which read my files in Async mode.

Comment: @Codeforgeek That comment was tongue in cheek I guess. Although `fs.lstat()` does not read files and you can't read files that are apparently non existent anyway. To be more serious: Obviously you are expecting files that are not there or `self.file` doesn't contain what you think it contains. It's not possible to help you without more information. Best would be a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Hi @BlackJack , i have tested my code with some cases, cases such as after execution of script moving the file into other location or deletion of files and i get the same error as such. 

Path is correct as per my team lead. Sorry for fs.lstat() file read crap. I was wrong in that.