# How to import local XML file and parse through it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, parsing, local

I have my JavaScript and XML files in the same folder. I'd like to be able to parse through the XML using the JavaScript, but I don't know how to get the JavaScript file to "talk" to the XML file. I've looked up ways, but they all involved server requests, which I don't need. How do I get the JavaScript to read-in the local XML file to make use of it?

I'd eventually want to be able to convert the XML to JSON and then have my JavaScript parse through that, which I think I know how to do. I just don't know how to get the JavaScript to take data from the XML. I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into using AJAX to load the external XML file.

Comment: What a weird question to close and flag as duplicate when this isn't asking anything to do with jQuery 

Answer (score 0):

Are your planning to use NodeJS for it? If so, see [The best node module for XML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890655/the-best-node-module-for-xml-parsing) . I've used xml-stream and it works pretty well. For a cross-browser solution: [Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing) .

Regarding the 'talking to the browser', if in NodeJS, use `fs` module. Otherwise (browser), use the FileAPI (see https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser) and then the crossbrowser solution above.

See the compatibility table for the FileAPI: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi (all modern browsers)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't considered using NodeJS. What would the benefit of doing so be?

Comment: That depends on your goal. NodeJS provides a runtime for javascript decoupled from the browser, letting you access local content with ease. If you're only doing some scripting, then nodejs would fit well. If you're willing to provide a great UI and something that you expect zero-config, then browser & web technologies are the best fit. 

There's actually a lot of benefits from both sides, just thought rapidly of two. Go check it out, you'll definetly enjoy!