# accesing xml content from node.js

Tags: node.js, marklogic

I have a bunch of XML documents in MarkLogic database.
I am working on a node.js middletier, it needs to pass on certain properties of all xml documents in a certain collection into a JSON array.

So far I have this:

```
var marklogic = require('marklogic');
var my = require('./my-connection.js');

var db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(my.connInfo);
var qb = marklogic.queryBuilder;

db.documents.query(
  qb.where(qb.collection("alert"))
).result( function(documents) {
    console.log('The alerts collection:')
    documents.forEach( function(document) {
      //console.log('\nURI: ' + document.uri);
      var aObj = document.content
      //var alert = aObj.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.com/sccs/alert","alert");
      console.log('Alert: ' + document.content);
    });
}, function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
});
```

Which gives me the content back.

Example result:

```
Alert: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<obj:object xmlns:obj="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object">
  <obi:metadata xmlns:obi="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi" createdBy="admin" createdDateTime="2015-09-23T20:42:48.562829Z" lastUpdatedBy="admin" lastUpdatedDateTime="2015-09-23T20:42:48.562829Z"/>
  <obj:label>Active</obj:label>
  <obj:type>alert</obj:type>
  <obj:id>41e718eb-a2e2-49e0-939a-68bb87c1e301</obj:id>
  <obj:content>
    <alert xmlns="http://example.com/sccs/alert">
      <obj:property sourceCount="1">
        <status>Active</status>
      </obj:property>
      <obj:property sourceCount="1">
        <position>{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[52.2, 4.3]}</position>
      </obj:property>
      <obj:property sourceCount="1">
        <scc:id xmlns:scc="http://example.com/sccs">2a65b4cc-acee-4675-a8ba-d8c5dfaac9dd</scc:id>
      </obj:property>
    </alert>
  </obj:content>
  <obj:workspaces>
    <obj:workspace id="Public"/>
  </obj:workspaces>
  <obj:sourceIds count="1">
    <source:id xmlns:source="http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/source">42aebdc7-41aa-4695-b514-2bb63f85d47c</source:id>
  </obj:sourceIds>
</obj:object>
```

Question:

I want to access for example the 'obj:content' element in this content.

In the Query Console I can do this by :

```
var alerts = fn.collection("alert").toArray();
var aXML = alerts[2].getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.com/sccs/alert","alert");
```

How can I do this from node.js?

(I do not understand the object type returned from the query in node.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MarkLogic node.js API returns XML documents as strings; you'll need to use an XML parser in order to query, project, or process that XML. There are lots of modules for interacting with XML on npm, see

- [The best node module for XML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890655/the-best-node-module-for-xml-parsing)
- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xml

You may find it easier to use a server-side transformation with MarkLogic, and convert your XML documents to JSON first: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/extensions#id_78179

Comment: +1 on server-side transformation. Build a transform that identifies the information you need and just returns that in JSON form, rather than converting the whole document.

Comment: I'll +1 that too. OBI has some default transforms for object XML to JSON, but odds are you'll want to write your own to do what Dave said - return only the data you want and in that format that's easiest for your client to work with.

Comment: yep i ended up using a server-side-transform