# How to read and print a value from an xml (javascript/node.js)

Tags: node.js

I need to read a value from an xml file and get that as an output.

```
<MessageReportEvent Id="9" Message="Traversal in 160.99495345777862" TimeStamp="1445229229"/>
```

The numeric value in the "Message" attribute is what I want to get

Comment: Try xml2js, see this for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890655/the-best-node-module-for-xml-parsing

Comment: Or try [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) npm package. Looks a lot like jQuery and can also handle HTML.