# How to create xml object in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am developing a javascript file while i will be using as external file in my html. In this js file I want to create an xml object but do not know how to use jquery in here and javascripts functions also do not work here. I have tried below as work around,

```
var xmlString = "<root></root>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

and

```
var XML = new XMLWriter();
```

Nothing worked out. I think i'll work when i include like,

But i want to develop external js file independently which is like,

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
//// and some other code
/// write this xml to a file
fs.writeFile("GSG_features3.xml", result, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
       console.log("The file was saved!");
});
//// and some other code
```

i am executing my script node `D:\Work > node myexternaljs.js`

How can i achieve this?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: This works but need to include jquery. How to include jquery in js file that is not known to me.

Comment: What is your plateform, browser or nodejs? For the browser you can either load the jquery script before your script (it will then be accessible with window.jQuery or window.$) or you can use a module bundler (like webpack , browserify or rollup). If nodejs or a bundler, you need to npm install jquery and then do `var jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: Why do you need jquery exactly? If your running node this is more suitable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890655/the-best-node-module-for-xml-parsing

Comment: I do not need jquery exactly. i just want to create an xml object and do some manipulations like find child, add child, add attributes .. only. any other option is also acceptable.